# Unable to get desired output for these two threads

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I am trying to implement volatile variables in java and i made a program for that first without volatile variables

```
public class test extends Thread 
{
private int value = 1;
@Override
public void run(){
if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("read thread"))  
  read();
    if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("write thread"))
    {
      try { 
          Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
  changeValue();
    }  
}

void read() {
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +" "+ value);

try {
  Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
}

// If another thread called changeValue()
// in the meantime the next print instruction is
// guaranteed to write "2"
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +" "+ value);
}

public void changeValue() {
 value = 2;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
   test obj=new test();
   Thread r=new Thread(obj);
   Thread w=new Thread(obj);
   r.setName("read thread");
   w.setName("write thread");
   r.start(); 
   w.start();      
}
}
```

the o/p is not as expected ..the read thread is taking the latest value ..ie the changed value which is done by write thread , this should be only when value is volatile

thanks in advance

Comment: "this should be only when value is volatile" - what makes you think that? If the variable is not declared volatile, you cannot say if the thread will see outdated value or not. Whereas if using it you can be sure. It's a "all chihuahuas are dogs but not all dogs are chihuahuas" - thing.

Comment: What is your expectation?

Comment: i want the read thread to pick out dated value

Comment: `System.out.println` is thread safe, so you'll always see the updated value.